# What is the kinetic energy of a proton as it is falling towards the core of the star?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, energy-conservation, protons

Given:

Star's mass = $1.99e10^{30}kg$

Type II supernova occurs (in a simple form: the outer layers of the star fall into the now inactive core at speeds of 126000km/s)

$10^{44}$ joules of energy is released in 2 seconds

After the event, the remaining neutron star of radius 12km has a mass of 2M (where mass of Sun is 1M = $1.99e^{30}$kg

Neutron star has a surface temperature of 1,000,000K

This is what I did:

$$KE=.5mv^2$$
$$KE=(0.5)(1.67262e-27kg)(126,000,000m/s)^2$$
$$KE=1.328e-11 J$$

My teacher said this was not the correct way to do this problem? Why not? I assumed that the proton was not accelerating because the problem stated that "The supernova occurs when the star stops producing energy in the core and it collapses, causing outer layers of the star to fall into the now inactive core at speeds of 126,000km/s (0.4200c). Once this material, which consists mostly of protons, impacts the core..."

Comment: Well,nearly  half the speed of light certainly puts us into the relativistic domain, so using classical kinetic energy certainly should not be accurate.

Comment: The protons obviously do accelerate, eventually reaching a speed of 0.42c (not 0.4200 c - while 126,000 "looks" accurate to 6 figures it really is probably accurate to only the first 3). You should be able to find their kinetic energy from the gravitational potential of the neutron star (start "infinitely far" away, end up at 12 km from a 2M mass.)

Comment: Note that the (or at least a) proper way to indicate scientific notation in LaTeX math-mode is `1.33 \times 10^{-11}`. Also, units should be typeset in upright text and preceded by a thin space. One way is to use `\,\mathrm{J}`. All together that looks like $1.33 \times 10^{-11}\,\mathrm{J}$.